# C# UWP Index out of range in for loop

Tags: c#, list, indexing, uwp

I am following a tutorial on youtube, and for some reason, even with having the exact same code, I get an exception:

`"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."`

What I am trying to do is, everytime I click the screen, the `i` value should increment, but it's not.

The code:

The variables:

```
public static float PointX, PointY, PhotonX, PhotonY;

public static List<float> PhotonXPOS = new List<float>();
public static List<float> PhotonYPOS = new List<float>();
public static List<float> Percent = new List<float>();
```

In the constructor:

```
Rect Bounds = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds;

 //Photon location.
 PhotonX = (float)Bounds.Width / 2; //Always at middle.
 PhotonY = (float)Bounds.Height; //Always at bottom.
```

In another method:

```
private void GameCanvas_Draw(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasControl sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
    {
        ///Display Projectiles.
        for (int i = 0; i < PhotonXPOS.Count; i++)
        {
            //Start and end point of a projectile.
            PointX = (PhotonX + (PhotonXPOS[i] - PhotonX) * Percent[i]);
            PointY = (PhotonY + (PhotonYPOS[i] - PhotonY) * Percent[i]);

            //Drawing of the Photons.
            args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(Scaling.Image(Photon), PointX - (25 * ScaleWidth), PointY - (25 * ScaleHeight));

            //Speed.
            Percent[i] += (0.050f * ScaleHeight);

            //If Photon goes out of screen at the top.
            if (PointY < 0f)
            {
                PhotonXPOS.RemoveAt(i);
                PhotonYPOS.RemoveAt(i);
                Percent.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }           
    }
```

The exception is given on the line

`PointY = (PhotonY + (PhotonYPOS[i] - PhotonY) * Percent[i]);`

It is as if `PhotonYPOS[i]` does not get incremented, but stays with the start value 0, then `i` gets incremented and gets higher than the List itself.

EDIT: This is the method called when a click on the screen is made (and items are added to the lists):

```
    public void GameCanvas_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(RoundEnded == true)
        {
            GameState = 0;
            Countdown = 6;
            RoundEnded = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Goes to next level.
            if (GameState == 0)
            {
                //Go to next level.
                GameState += 1;
                //Start round timer.
                RoundTimer.Start();                  
            }
            else if(GameState > 0)
            {
                //Add Photons.
                PhotonXPOS.Add((float)e.GetPosition(GameCanvas).X);
                PhotonXPOS.Add((float)e.GetPosition(GameCanvas).Y);
                Percent.Add(0f);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about Percent[i] does it have the same number of items as PhotonXPOS ?

Comment: Yes, it is declared right under PhotonXPOS and PhotonYPOS if you look at the top :)

Comment: Very little code to get a reproduceable setup here. So only speculations from me: 1st. does Percent has the same dimension(element count) as ```PhotonYPOS``` and ```PhotonXPOS```?; 2nd ```GameCanvas_Draw``` is invoked when you click at the screen?; 3rd: is there some kind of threading involved? It could be a Race Condition where draw is executed rigth between an update(element appended) of ```PhotonXPOS``` and ```PhotonYPOS```

Comment: 1. Yes Percent has the same element count.
2. No it is not invoked when clicking a screen, it just draws the image.
3. No threads at all used.

Comment: So where is your logic to add new Elements to thats lists, since they are empty in the provided code?

Comment: Added to the post.

Comment: look at those 2 lines my friend: ```PhotonXPOS.Add((float)e.GetPosition(GameCanvas).X);
                PhotonXPOS.Add((float)e.GetPosition(GameCanvas).Y);``` the 2nd oney should have an ```PhotonYPOS``` in it

Comment: oh wow, that solved it! I cannot believe it, I have been trying for hours. Thank you! How can I accept your solution.

Comment: just posted an answer below, if you could accept it , thx :)

Comment: Added a solution to the skipping index problem in your loop, if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Typo
As stated in the comments:

change this

    `//Add Photons.
    PhotonXPOS.Add((float)e.GetPosition(GameCanvas).X);
    PhotonXPOS.Add((float)e.GetPosition(GameCanvas).Y);
    Percent.Add(0f);`

to that

    `//Add Photons.
    PhotonXPOS.Add((float)e.GetPosition(GameCanvas).X);
    PhotonYPOS.Add((float)e.GetPosition(GameCanvas).Y);
    Percent.Add(0f);`

For the Second Problem: skipping items, you should decrease `i` after removing the last item.

Example
List before
`1 2 3 4 5`
i is 2 in this case, pointing to Element 3, 
now you remove elment 2, i is increased at the end of the loop to 3, which points to Element 5

List after
`1 2 4 5`
i=3

In this case Element 4 with index 2 is never used.

Suggested Change:

```
if (PointY < 0f)
{
    PhotonXPOS.RemoveAt(i);
    PhotonYPOS.RemoveAt(i);
    Percent.RemoveAt(i);
    i--;// in the next loop handle index i again (i-1+1=i)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented the change.

Answer (score 1):

You iterate over `PhotonXPOS.Count` but sometimes you remove using `PhotonXPOS.RemoveAt(i);` that's why `i` goes over the array count.

One solution is to go reverse `for (int i = PhotonXPOS.Count; i > 0; i--)`

Comment: But this condition is checked after each loop, isnt it? It causes only to skip the next element when removing the current one.